# Component Angular 4. Jhipster 4.x

Tags: angular, jhipster

I have created a new entity with "jhipster: entity", and it has created the whole structure correctly, including the entry in the menu.

I now want to integrate it into another screen. And with the main component selector:

```
@Component({
selector: 'jhi-documento-oportunidad',
templateUrl: './documento-oportunidad.component.html'
})
```

In the screen that I want to add I put the following:

```
<jhi-documento-oportunidad></jhi-documento-oportunidad>
```

But he does not do anything, he does not paint anything.

Someone can help me, I do not know what is past.

Thank you.

Comment: did you declare it in your module?

Comment: Yes, what I'm seeing is that it's inside another Component, in the view where I'm adding it belongs to another component.

Comment: augustine : I have changed the module, the one of the parent component and already it paints to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is open Developer Tools and check if the selector appears in the DOM. If so maybe the html code of your component is wrong.